# How to start executables through command prompt with space named files and without command prompt waiting program to close?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file

I would like to create shortcuts to some executable files (exe, bat, com...) on Windows 7 using bat files, but I had some troubles with that:

1. `start notepad.exe`works perfectly, but `start Foxit Reader.exe` or `start "Foxit Reader.exe"` will not function. How to use `start` command with files named with space characters?
2. `call notepad.exe` or `start "Foxit Reader.exe"` or just `notepad.exe` or `"Foxit Reader.exe"` works but a command prompt is opened and remains opened until the user close it or called executable. Any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read help for `start` carefully. And `start` does not wait for started process termination by default (there is `/wait` flag for "waiting" mode).

```
start "" "Foxit Reader.exe"
```

Comment: Oh my! If I could put that question eligible for bounty today, I would assign 50 points to you :)

Comment: Note to self: Type faster.

Answer (score 4):

Start seems to take the first parameter as the title if there's a space in it.

So while this did not work for me:

```
start "c:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe"
```

This *did*: `start "" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe"`

Comment: Although @maximus answered at first, your answer explain why `start` does not function with quotes...

Answer (score 3):

Use quotes like this:

start "" "Y:\foo bar\xyz"

If the first argument is quoted, start assumes it's the title for the new console window, so launch a new console window. The following argument will then be correctly interpreted as the command to run / file to open.